# REMOVE or replace $ characters from a string

Tags: regex, plsql

Can anyone help me out on how i can drop $ characters from a string in oracle plsql using REGEX_SUBSTR or REGEX_REPLACE function??

```
e.g: TEXT_ID$ => TEXT_ID
     $CUSTOMER_ORDER => CUSTOMER_ORDER
```

Help is much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the REGEXP_REPLACE function to eliminate '$' character form string.

you can user select REGEXP_REPLACE (your_string,'[$]','') from dual;

Example: select REGEXP_REPLACE ('$CUST$OMER$$$$_OR$$$DER$$$$','[$]','') from dual;

output: CUSTOMER_ORDER

I hope I answered your question